# Azure DevOps - Custom Build Task Extension is published, shared and installed in my private organization; but cannot be used in pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm learning Azure DevOps. I'm interested in creating a custom build task to get a build artifact from a pipeline and send it to a server. I tried creating a simple custom build task extension and installing it in my organization.

The extension is displayed as installed, with a version of "1.0.4". I tried using it in a pipeline, in YAML file as "- task: ExtentionTest@1", but I'm getting an error "An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. wrong number of segments".

The custom build task doesn't show in the last of tasks next to the YAML file either. Is there a correct method to use a custom build task in a pipeline?